# Tables with both CASCADE constraints and a delete proc?

Tags: sql-server

I'm poking through a 3rd party database and came across something confusing.

A table of `Assets` contains the object model's root objects, with many other tables containing a `AssetId` fkey. `Assets` has cascade delete constraints to clear out anyone referring to it if an Asset is deleted.

However, there is also an `SP_delete_asset` PROC, and reading through it it has the exact same list as the constraints.

So can anyone offer a reason why someone might write a (lengthy) PROC for this when the constraints appear to already do this?

Comment: ask the person who made that SP, i'm sure s/he will give you more explanation.

Answer (score 0):

1. 1) The developer first wrote the proc and then someone told the
   developer that he or she could have used the cascade clause
   2) The   developer wanted to verify that cascade worked the same way as code did. 
   3) Don't assume competence or rational actions coming from developers.

Comment: I hope my editing did not result in a second answer. I am trying to answer once.

Comment: It did. Delete one.